# Enviar mensaje a telegram desde arduino con placa ethernet

Tags: arduino

estoy tratando de enviar un mensaje a la API de telegram desde mi placa arduino uno con una placa Ethernet shield pero no logro hacerlo, me bota un error, este es el codigo que he aplicado:

```js
 #include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

// Configurar la dirección IP, máscara de subred y dirección IP del gateway
byte mac[] = { 0x00, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDE, 0x02 };
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 177);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 0, 1);
IPAddress myDns(192, 110, 40, 105);

// Configurar el token de acceso del bot de Telegram
String token = "{token goes here}";

// Configurar el chat ID del destinatario del mensaje
String chat_id = "{chat ID goes here}";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {}


if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // Check for Ethernet hardware present
    if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware) {
      Serial.println("Ethernet shield was not found.  Sorry, can't run without hardware. :(");
      while (true) {
        delay(1); // do nothing, no point running without Ethernet hardware
      }
    }
    if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF) {
      Serial.println("Ethernet cable is not connected.");
    }
    // try to configure using IP address instead of DHCP:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, myDns);
  } 


  // Inicializar la conexión Ethernet
  //Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, subnet);

  // Enviar el mensaje a Telegram
  sendMessageToTelegram("Hola desde Arduino!");
}

void loop() {
  // No hay nada más que hacer en el bucle principal
}

void sendMessageToTelegram(String message) {
  // Crear un objeto JSON que contenga el mensaje que se desea enviar
  DynamicJsonDocument doc(200);
  doc["chat_id"] = chat_id;
  doc["text"] = message;

  // Convertir el objeto JSON a una cadena de caracteres
  String json;
  serializeJson(doc, json);

  // Establecer la conexión con la API de Telegram
  EthernetClient client;
  if (!client.connect("api.telegram.org", 443)) {
    Serial.println("Error al conectar con la API de Telegram");
    return;
  }

  // Enviar la solicitud HTTP POST a la API de Telegram
  client.println("POST /bot" + token + "/sendMessage HTTP/1.1");
  client.println("Host: api.telegram.org");
  client.println("Content-Type: application/json");
  client.println("Connection: close");
  client.println("Content-Length: " + String(json.length()));
  client.println();
  client.println(json);

  // Leer la respuesta de la API de Telegram
  String response;
  while (client.connected()) {
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
    if (line == "\r") {
      break;
    }
  }
  while (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    response += c;
  }
  Serial.println(response);
```

Pero el monitor serial me bota el siguiente error:.

```html
<html>

<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>

<body>

<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>

<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>

<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0</center>

</body>

</html>
```

Entiendo que es por el tema de Https, saben si existe alguna manera de poder enviar este mensaje con el hardware que tengo? ya que en esta placa ya tengo montado todo un sistema de sensores de temperatura, consumo de corriente y apertura de puertas, y si o si debe ser por ethernet, la idea es enviar una alerta cuando la temperatura llegue a cierto dato, (aunque el código completo no es este, este es solo un ejemplo que encontré para enviar mensajes a arduino), ahora si existe otra manera de poder enviar ese mensaje en tiempo real también me serviría, agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Edito: no me permite editar el mensaje, olvide poner el Saludo al inicio, pido disculpas de antemano.

Comment: No es verdá, la pregunta siempre se puede [edit]. Saludos :)

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente, lo único que necesite cambiarse sea usar

```
client.connectSSL("api.telegram.org", 443)
```

en lugar del connect a secas.

Otra opción puede ser usar otra librería para gestionar las peticiones HTTP, como lo indican en [esta otra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60343909/236345) respuesta.

Si no está disponible, es posible que [no haya](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/ethernet-post-data-via-https/584139/5) [implementación](https://reference.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/ethernet/ethernetclient/) para soportar los cálculos necesarios para cifrar la comunicación :/

Comment: le he cambiado y me da este error el monitor.. Compilation error: 'class EthernetClient' has no member named 'connectSSL'; did you mean 'connect'?, ,mirando el link que me compartes veo que todo esta enfocado a hacerlo por medio de conexion WIFI, y con otro codigo que encontre y una placa Arduino con modulo esp8266 integrado que tengo si lo envia, pero necesariamente debo hacerlo con la placa ethernet shield que tengo.

Comment: @diegocordoba Pues [parece](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/ethernet-post-data-via-https/584139/5) que no se puede :(